# QuerySyntaxException: Table is not mapped [Update Table BOMmodel Set PA13 = Materialvalue + ReqQTY ]

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa

i'm trying to update a column with the sum of two other columns(Materialvalue , ReqQTY) as you can see above

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.example.demo2.model.BOMmodel;

public interface BOMrepository extends JpaRepository<BOMmodel, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("Update Table BOMmodel Set PA13 = Materialvalue + ReqQTY ")
      int updatePA();
}
```

the entity looks like this

```
@Table(name = "bom_table")
@Entity
public class BOMmodel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;
    public String ComponentNo;
    public Float ReqQTY;
    public String MatGroup;
    public Float Materialvalue;
    public Float PA13;
    public String kw;
```

but I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'BOMrepos'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BOMrepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.example.demo2.repository.BOMrepository.updatePA()!

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'BOMrepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract void com.example.demo2.repository.BOMrepository.updatePA()!

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Table is not mapped [Update Table BOMmodel Set PA13 = Materialvalue + ReqQTY ]
```

i made some research and i found out that using the table name instead of the entity is the usual cause of this error but it's not the case.
so please any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update bom_table Set PA13 = Materialvalue + ReqQTY
```

use that

Comment: thanks alot @Mayank you inspired me to resolve this problem. what i did is to delete the line `@Table(name = "bom_table")` and i changed the repository code to this  `@Transactional @Modifying
    @Query("Update BOMmodel Set PA13 = Materialvalue + ReqQTY ")
      int updatePA();`    now it works like a charm

Comment: Welcome.when you deals your problem you learn many things..so keep going on..

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found is to delete the line `@Table(name = "bom_table")` and change the repository code to this      @Transactional @Modifying @Query("Update BOMmodel Set PA13 = Materialvalue + ReqQTY ") int updatePA();
Now it works like a charm.